# SQL (Oracle) Updating multiple rows with calculated values (distance by Pythagorean theorem)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

How do I update all rows with calculated data derived from the values in two other columns of the same record?

Here's the situation:

I have a table called `customers`. It had 4 columns - `Customer_ID`, `Customer_Name`, `Coordinate_X` and `Coordinate_Y`'. Since creating and filling the table with data I have added an empty 5th column called `Distance`

What I'd like to do is fill the `Distance` column with the calculated distances from (0,0) to the locations specified in the `Coordinate_X` and `Coordinate_Y` columns of each row. I figured I could use Pythagoras's theory - and the correct values come up when I use the query:

```
Select SQRT(Power(customers.coordinate_x,2) + Power(customers.coordinate_y,2)) from customers
```

I fiddled about trying to make a trigger - failed that through lack of experience. 
Then I tried to fill the column using queries - failed that too.

I've been trying things like this;

```
update customers set distance = (Select SQRT(Power(customers.coordinate_x,2) + Power(customers.coordinate_y,2)) from customers)
```

Nothing's working - the best I'm getting is `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags, because the error is an Oracle error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is simpler than what you are doing:

```
update customers
    set distance = SQRT(Power(coordinate_x, 2) + Power(coordinate_y, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is correct. However, for this particular example, it's better to use a virtual column and you won't have to update the distance after changing a customer's coordinates:

```
create table customers (
  customer_id number,
  customer_name varchar(255),
  coordinate_x number,
  coordinate_y number,
  distance  number generated always as (SQRT(Power(coordinate_x, 2) + Power(coordinate_y, 2))) VIRTUAL
```

);

See this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6db3/4

Comment: Good answer, but the OP should know that this will only work in Oracle 11g and up.